# Porting to new Android Studio - badAuthentication with Google Login Services?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've looked a lot, but haven't found the answer to this.  I've been doing Android development and working with Android Studio.  v1.0 is out and I've upgraded.  My old projects didn't port (gradle incompatibility) so I made a new project, killed the unrelated files, and replaced with my files from the last working version (made under Android Studio .6 or something).

It fails during compilation trying to do some kind of authentication with Google Login Services (and I don't use any services).  It references my email address - it throws a "badAuthentication" with my email address.  I have grepped all through the files for either my email address or a reference to google, and all I can find is my email address in the usual place in my comments.  No .gradle or .xml or .iml (or any) file seems to reference google.  Where is this authentication effort coming from?  I'd like to comment it out.

Thanks

Comment: Post the error message, please.

Comment: I think this is related to the "Sign in with Google" option (right-hand icon in the toolbar) instead of anything with your project.

Comment: I haven't been able to find the "sign in with google" but I'm trying.
On edit: I found the icon, but it just allows me to log in, I need to know where this is controlled.

Comment: As far as actual error messages, they take various forms, but this is typical:
12-12 12:30:43.048    1699-5395/? V/GoogleLoginService﹕ Returning error intent with: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gsf.login/com.google.android.gsf.login.LoginActivity}
12-12 12:30:48.018    1699-3238/? I/GLSUser﹕ GLS error: BadAuthentication <my email> print

Comment: I also get this upon compile:  
12-12 12:39:59.808  10606-10620/? D/CalendarSyncAdapter﹕ Unable to get calendar account
    com.google.android.apiary.AuthenticationException: Could not get an auth token

Comment: Update: I couldn't track this down - I suspect it has something to do with the templates specified.  I wiped everything (except my code) and installed a new studio and a project with no activity, and replaced my code.  Still some bugs left, but I seem to be beyond the google api login thing.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I couldn't track this down - I suspect it has something to do with the templates specified. I wiped everything (except my code) and installed a new studio and a project with no activity, and replaced my code. It works now.  So, no idea what caused it; I just gave up on the upgrading (which Android Studio seems to have a spotty record on) and just did a full replacement and rebuild.